# React-native navigationbar color change error

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would like to change my navigationbar background color , but return to me : TypeError: Object is not a function(evaluating 'renderHeader');

How can i fix this error?

```
 static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        title: 'Login', 
        header: {
            title: "Title",
            style: {
              backgroundColor: 'red'
            },
            tintColor: 'red'
          }
    });
```

Comment: "(evaluating 'renderHeader')" - Can you share `renderHeader `?

Comment: I don't have renderHeader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
static navigationOptions = () => ({
    title: 'Contact Us',
    headerTintColor: Colors.Green,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
  });
```

To hide `navigationbar` for specific page

```
static navigationOptions = {
         header:null
    }
```

Comment: so how can display:none navigationbar ?

Comment: Hide navigation overall or for particular screen?

Answer (score 2):

I guess, `navigationOptions` should be Object. Try this:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Login', 
    header: {
        title: "Title",
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'red'
        },
        tintColor: 'red'
      }
};
```